# How do you minimize a window in the Visual Studio 2010 RC editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using the Visual Studio 2010 RC. Sometimes when I am working on a code file, I would like to minimize it.

In Visual Studio 2008 I just switched to MDI mode. Then I could minimize. In 2010, I can undock the window by dragging the tab, and that gets me half way to MDI, but I see no way to minimize the window.

Does anyone know how to do this?

**Update - Closely-related question**: For those of you that used MDI, how are you getting by? I like to have 4 documents open at once, in a 2x2 matrix. For example I like to look at one controller/view pair while working on another, for the sake of comparison. Then, maybe I edit my repository file, and I want to get back to my 4 windows. This is where I would minimize. Anyone have a workaround? How have you adapted?

**Update 2 - Vote up my suggestion if you want this feature:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/536110/please-offer-this-ultra-quick-alternative-to-a-minimize-feature-for-the-vs-2010-ide#**

Comment: I believe I saw someone on SO say that MDI mode is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its disabled. I pressed Alt-Space in the undocked window and minimise was disabled.

Comment: I think this may be all there is to it. But please allow me to leave this open a bit longer, in case people have work-arounds or other good discussion.